Question about the definition of a non-singular matrix
Could anyone please check if my understanding below is correct?
According to $\det (A^T) = \det (A)$. If $\det (A^T) = \det (A) \neq 0$, then $A$ is non-singular. This means that the columns are linearly independent. Moreover, because $\det (A^T) = \det (A)$, this means that the rows must also be linearly independent. Therefore, we say that $A$ is non-singular if the columns (or rows) are linearly independent.
Is this why the definition of non-singular particularly mentions "columns (or rows)"?

Yes. You're correct. Actually $|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}C_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ij}C_{ij}$ where $C$ represents the co-factor of the element.

@Gwen Oh right, the recursive formula for determinant. I love when concepts/theorems are interconnected, where one explains the other and vice versa. Thank you.

Yes, you are absolutely right, everything you wrote is true. Usually people think of non-singularity as nonzero determinant. Singular (not only in this context) usually means something unusual, or not well-behaving.

That's great, thank you!
